# Recursive Shadow DOM VS. Light DOM

Tags: dom, browser, shadow-dom

I am a bit confused about *Shadow DOM* vs. *Light DOM*. I couldn't find clear information about whether or not the *Shadow DOM* is recursive, i.e. whether or not a *Shadow DOM* can contain one or more nested *Shadow DOMs* (at least, the model Angular is using suggests it has to be recursive). If so, then isn't the *Light DOM* just a synonym for something like the "root shadow DOM"? If that's the case, I don't think the terminology is very apt (light VS shadow).

Comment: Shadow trees can be nested, yes. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I never found this fact stated clearly in the docs/online. And I was confused about the binary naming „light“ vs. „shadow“, where in reality it is a tree-like structure of view encapsulation. It is not only valid to say that shadow dom lives *in the shadow* of the light dom, but also that shadow dom lives *in the shadow* of another shadow dom, implying that one shadow dom is the **light-side** of the other. „Where there is shadow, there must be light!“, but light in this sentence does not necessarily mean „light dom“.

Comment: I think "Shadow DOM" and "Light DOM", at least as the specs are today, are misnomers. There's just the one DOM. The document accessed by the DOM contains the hosts of "shadow trees", which can contain their own hosts to further shadow trees. But in this context, light and shadow are relative terms. Each shadow tree has its own light tree, the tree which contains its host. In the case of a nested shadow tree, *its* light tree is itself a shadow tree. It may be the light/shadow analogy is not ideal in understanding this.

Comment: @Alohci that‘s exactly what I mean!!